# How can I fill the entire image into a span that is small?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project where clicking a button will generate a random span(in a form of a circle) that blinks on a webpage. The problem is that I'm trying to set the background image of span to be a local .jpg file, and only a tiny bit of the image fills the span.

[Only the dog ear is populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo4qP.png)

My css looks like this:

```css
.blinkyDancer{
  background: url(../xyz/dog.png);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

What can I do to make the whole dog's face filled into that span background?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the background image size using `background-size` css attribute.

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add background-size. it could be contain or cover check what is better.

```
.blinkyDancer{
  background: url(../xyz/dog.png);
  background-size:contain;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've specified the size of the element, but not the size of the image itself.  Add this to your css:

```
  background-size: 90px 90px;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also resize the image to meet the requirements, there are many free sites you can use